# How to use environmental variables for database names in Teradata to create table and stored procedures?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, teradata

We have DEV, UAT and PRD environments. We recently created 20 new schema and 120 tables. Suppose, PO_DEV_SPD is the database name. I have created tables under this schema. Now, I want to use environmental variable instead of database name. Like $SPDDB.MY_ACCOUNT. How can I use this env variable while creating table as well as in stored procedure.

Update: When creating DDLs

```
CREATE MULTISET TABLE $SPDDB.tbl_employee
(
name VARCHAR(20),
id INT,
roll_no INT
)
PRIMARY INDEX (id, roll_no)
```

Can I use env variable using shell scripting while creating DDLs/DMLs?

Comment: No database name in the `CREATE TABLE` and `DATABASE DEV;` before running the DDL?

Comment: @dnoeth while creating the tables we mention the qualifier.tablename. This qualifier is nothing but database name/schema name in my case. Now, I want to use shell scripting to create env variables and use them while creating DDLs and DMLs.

Comment: You can form a SQL script in the shell and then submit it for execution through a client app.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that should point you in the right direction.

The paths to `BTQLOG` and `LOGON` are fictional and do not represent good practices. Replace with paths that are appropriate for your environment and the security parameters enforced by your environment.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
SPDDB='PROD'
BTQLOG='/var/opt/log/bteq.log'
LOGON='/var/opt/logon/bteq.con'
#
bteq <<EOBTQ > $BTQLOG 2>&1
.RUN file=${LOGON}

CREATE MULTISET TABLE $SPDDB.tbl_employee
(
name VARCHAR(20),
id INT,
roll_no INT
)
PRIMARY INDEX (id, roll_no);

.QUIT ERRORLEVEL;

EOBTQ
#
#
STATUS=$?
#
exit $STATUS
```